# nodeJS not found on firebase

Tags: node.js, firebase

:)

i have a nodeJS app on firebase, the front of this app is do with ReactJS.

As long as I do not update the web page everything works perfectly, but if I update, nodeJS takes priority over the url and displays an error because no action is defined for the url

I made a sendFile to the index.html for each url like that :

```
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile('index.html', {root: `${__dirname}/../public`});
});
```

Locally, it works perfectly, I can update without losing the page where I am, but when I deploy my application on firebase it does not work. during the update it shows me "not found" and that in the console of the browser
[console of the brower](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q7Cve.png)

I thought that it could not find the file because firebase arranged them differently but I did not find anything concerning the architecture of firebase :/

I don't know if it's completely clear, I don't know how to explain it better ^^ '

thanks for your time :)

Comment: Can you post your `firebase.json` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found!, firebase apparently does not allow the code to leave the function folder (donation impossible to do ../public), so I simply put the public folder in the function folder .

Its gives its:

```
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile('index.html', {root: `${__dirname}/public`});
});
```